# testing a substring with indexOF() javascript

Tags: javascript, string, indexof

I'm trying to check a substring using `indexOf()` .It should return true when the string being tested for is there and false otherwise. For some reason my code is always returning true ?

Why is this code not working, how can it be fixed ?

```
function checkSpam(str) {

if(str == str.indexOf('yyy') || str.indexOf('xxx')) {
    return true;
}

return false;
}
```

Comment: indexOf returns position, a number, not a str, so why are you compare it to one?

Comment: The easiest way is `return /xxx|yyy/.test(str)`, you don't even need an `if` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't always be `true`.

You have a condition that consists of two parts. The first part `str == str.indexOf('yyy')` will always be false, unless `str` has the value `"-1"`. The second part `str.indexOf('xxx')` will always evaluate to true, unless the string starts with `xxx` as the result of the `indexOf` call will zero.

So, if `str` is `"-1"` or if it doesn't start with `xxx`, the result will be `true`.

If you want to check if the string contains `xxx` or `yyy` you should check the result of `indexOf` in both parts of the condition:

```
if (str.indexOf('yyy') != -1 || str.indexOf('xxx') != -1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

indexOf() of Javascript returns a number, not a string, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Your could should be:

```
if(-1 != str.indexOf('yyy') || -1 != str.indexOf('xxx')) {
 return true;
}
```